# div inside div not moving

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code -

this is my html -

```
<div class="users_panel">
<div clas="users_list">
<h5>Online users</h5>
<ul>
  <li>user 1</li>
  <li>user 1</li>
  <li>user 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS -

```
enter code here
.users_panel {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EBF4FB;
  height: 600px;
  width: 264px;
}
```

but if i am adding the following css -

```
.users_list  {

margin: 60px 0 0 0;
}
```

but it is not moving the inner div i.e. users_list at all, please someone help me!!!

Comment: You have misspelled `class` attribute for `.users_list` element. Change `clas` to `class`. However using `margin-top` causes margin collapsing in this case. As an alternative, you can use `padding-top` for the `.users_panel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error in class name, you have miss an `s` try this:

```
<div class="users_list">
```

instead of this:

```
<div clas="users_list">
```

and close it at the end of the code with `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the outer div.

```
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Have To Close `div` tag And you write `class` attribute `clas`**